# confused about flash support on smartphones

Tags: apache-flex

From Adobe docs:  labs.adobe.com/technologies/flex/mobile/faq.html#differences
it looks like with present SDK (4.5 "Hero" ) only standalone flex app for AIR are supported on mobile devices.
So can someone explain how i can run "YouTube" clips on my Nexus One phone with Android 2.2?
Thanks,
-V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application doesn't use Flash video instead the video stream is sent via some other protocol and decoded via the application rather than being run through flash (has the same player chrome feel as the flash version online so I could see the confusion).  This doesn't mean it's actually Flash.  Also the Hero SDK is for developing applications that will be turned into apk files or native packages so the code isn't really running on a flash plugin (that I'm aware of) but rather is converted to native code, if I'm wrong someone please correct me.

With the newer OS that supports Flash you can view flash content in web pages, I now have support on the MyTouch3G thx T-Mobile and on a Galaxy Tab.  The Hero demo app works okay, but feels sluggish in the transitions department.  Flash on web pages works okay on the tablet but is still a bit delayed and the mouse pointer translation from the touch point seems slightly off (think I have to touch right above what I want to click, can be challenging).

Comment: You're almost right.  The Hero SDK features for developing Android apps do turn your Flex code into apk files.  However, you need the AIR runtime installed on the device for those apps to work.  It does not turn them into native device code.  (The iPhone Packager does turn your SWFs into native device code bundled with some version of the AIR SDK).

Comment: @flextras thx for the correction and clarification +s all around.  Also to add to your post really, there is a native YouTube application that I imagine doesn't utilize Flash in any way, going to the YouTube site you get the flash player version.  There is however an HTML5 version of youtube http://www.youtube.com/html5, and if I go to the m.youtube.com site I get links like this rtsp://v4.cache1.c.youtube.com/CjYLENy73wIaLQnl49xWJfGGphMYJCAkFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSBXdhdGNoYMPBurjVgP3LSww=/0/0/0/video.3gp rtsp 3gp.

Comment: what are you referring as "application" - some third party, youtube specific plugin?

Comment: Thought it was installed by default but in the android application menu I have YouTube check the market.

Answer (score 1):

The Nexus One, running Android 2.2 supports the Flash Player 10.1 for mobile.

Saying that, there are two options:

1. YouTube detects the browser type and serves up an experience optimized for that browser.  Does surfing YouTube on Android actually use Flash?  Or do they have a mobile specific player, like they do for iPhone?  I honestly don't know.
2. The Video Player on YouTube was built using ActionScript / Flash Pro and has no Flex dependencies.  This approach would allow YouTube to optimize a mobile player much more than a Flex application would.

Keep in mind, ActionScript 3 is ActionScript 3.  And Flex is ACtionScript 3.  There is no reason you can't deply / run a Flex app on Flash Player 10.1 for mobile.  Just don't expect performance to be up to speed.

'Supported' and 'Sorks' are two different concepts.  Adobe does not [yet] support use of Flex on mobile because the performance is horrible.  Flex was designed with a very different use case in mind.  The Mobile SDK included in Flex Hero is an optimized component set strictly for mobile devices.